# I have used -webkit-column to divide paragraph.But Chrome showing top spacing in paragraph for arabic text

Tags: css

My Css file.

```
p{-webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    text-align:justify;
    -webkit-column-gap: 106px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 106px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 106px;
}
```

here is the JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p88w7rdr/